# Twitter compose dialog

Tags: android, twitter

I am using the new fabric twitter compose to share things on twitter.When I click share, the share dialog appears.Then when I click close, it doesn't return to my app but instead it goes to the twitter app. Is it possible to alter this behaviour and return to my app?

Comment: When you click hardware back button it will be returned to your app right?

Comment: yes it does return to the app.

Comment: Seems to be the default behavior. Happening in my app to. There doesn't seem to be any workaround for this as of now unless they update their twitter app.